# Regex with m flag in Perl vs. Python

Tags: python, regex, multiline

I'm trying to automatically translate some simple Perl code with a regex to Python, and I'm having an issue. Here is the Perl code:

```perl
$stamp='[stamp]';
$message = "message\n";
$message =~ s/^/$stamp/gm;
print "$message";
[stamp]message
```

Here is my Python equivalent:

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(re.compile("^", re.M), "[stamp]", "message\n", count=0)
'[stamp]message\n[stamp]'
```

Note the answer is different (it has an extra `[stamp]` at the end).  How do I generate code that has the same behavior for the regex?

Comment: `^` with `re.M` matches the start of _every_ line and the `\n` makes the Python example _two_ lines, hence two replacements.

Comment: Without the `re.M` the example would be right but I don't know Perl's behavior on other examples.

Comment: Seems like this may be an incompatibility between PCRE and Python RE "multiline" modes. With [`re.M` in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.M), "the pattern character '^' matches at the beginning of the string and at the beginning of each line (immediately following each newline)". It looks like PCRE goes one step further and requires `^` to be at the start of a valid _POSIX line_ (i.e., _terminated_ with a newline).

Comment: If you just want to prefix the string with `[start]`, by the way, using a regular expression seems like overkill.

Comment: It's prefixing every line of a potentially multi-line string, and again, I'm automatically translating the perl code to python.

Comment: Side-note: `re.sub(re.compile(...), ...)` is a weird/verbose/redundant way to spell `re.compile(...).sub(...)`. And `count=0` is the default, so passing it is unnecessary. You could simplify `re.sub(re.compile("^", re.M), "[stamp]", "message\n", count=0)` to `re.compile("^", re.M).sub("[stamp]", "message\n")`.

Comment: Re: Side note: Pythonizer is an automatic translator from perl to python = it generates the code in a certain order to handle things, like first it handles all flags except the G flag, then it handles that last by setting count=0 vs count=1.  I understand the code may look a little funny but it works.

Comment: Seem to behave the same https://regex101.com/r/uyT1i2/1 and https://regex101.com/r/mNTTeP/1 could be that EOS `\Z` overrides `^` in regards to newline ending strings. You could rule out ambiguity with `(?m)^(?!\a|\Z)` or `(?m)(?!\a|\Z)^`

Comment: Fixed in the latest Pythonizer: https://github.com/snoopyjc/pythonizer/issues/286

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl and Python's regex engines differ slightly on the definition of a "line"; Perl does not consider the empty string following a trailing newline in the input string to be a line, Python does.

Best solution I can come up with is to change `"^"` to `r"^(?=.|\n)"` (note `r` prefix on string to make it a raw literal; all regex should use raw literals). You can also simplify a bit by just calling methods on the compiled regex *or* call `re.sub` with the uncompiled pattern, and since `count=0` is already the default, you can omit it. Thus, the final code would be either:

```
re.compile(r"^(?=.|\n)", re.M).sub("[stamp]", "message\n")
```

or:

```
re.sub(r"^(?=.|\n)", "[stamp]", "message\n", flags=re.M)
```

Even better would be:

```
start_of_line = re.compile(r"^(?=.|\n)", re.M)  # Done once up front

start_of_line.sub("[stamp]", "message\n")  # Done on demand
```

avoiding recompiling/rechecking compiled regex cache each time, by creating the compiled regex just once and reusing it.

Alternative solutions:

1. Split up the lines in a way that will match Perl's definition of a line, then use the non-`re.MULTILINE` version of the regex per line, then shove them back together, e.g.:

   ```
   start_of_line = re.compile(r"^")  # Compile once up front without re.M

   # Split lines, keeping ends, in a way that matches Perl's definition of a line
   # then substitute on line-by-line basis
   ''.join([start_of_line.sub("[stamp]", line) for line in "message\n".splitlines(keepends=True)])
   ```
2. Strip a single trailing newline, if it exists, up-front, perform regex substitution, add back newline (if applicable):

   ```
   message = '...'
   if message.endswith('\n'):
       result = start_of_line.sub("[stamp]", message[:-1]) + '\n'
   else:
       result = start_of_line.sub("[stamp]", message)
   ```

Neither option is as succinct/efficient as trying to tweak the regex, but if arbitrary user-supplied regex must be handled, there's always going to be a corner case, and pre-processing to something that removes the Perl/Python incompatibility is a lot safer.

Comment: Thanks - do you think this solution will work with any user supplied regex with the M flag, or just '^'?

Comment: @snoopyjc: It'll handle *most* cases where a leading `^` in the pattern is changed to `^(?=.|\n)`. But if the user used alternation to put a `^` later in the pattern, e.g. `r"abc|^"`, oops, that `^` really did mean start of line and we missed it. Regex is crazy.

Comment: @snoopyjc: I just posted an alternative that makes use of `str.splitlines` to make Python actually split into individual lines, so you don't use `re.M` at all, and the problem goes away. Obviously going to be slower, but I think it's safe for line-oriented regex patterns. Can't swear to anything in the presence of regex though, it's kinda nuts all the way down.

Comment: Oh I was just going to append (?=.|\n) to the user's regex whenever they used the M flag.  Like if they said ^m I would put ^m(?=.|\n).  Should I instead change that one to ^(?=.|\n)m ??  Looks like I need a bunch of test  cases.

Comment: @snoopyjc: `^m(?=.|\n)` is definitely wrong, for an input like `"abc\nm"`, where `^m` would match and replace that final `m` (on both Perl and Python), but `^m(?=.|\n)` would not (on either), because there is no character of any kind after the `m`. `^(?=.|\n)m` would work just fine for that case, but you'd have to write a regex pattern parser to reliably figure out the correct place to insert the `(?=.|\n)` if you wanted to handle fully arbitrary regex that were otherwise compatible with both Perl and Python regex syntax. The edge cases will kill you eventually.

Comment: Understood - thanks!  Will start writing those tests and see what works.

Comment: Implemented!  https://github.com/snoopyjc/pythonizer/issues/286

Answer (score 1):

Perl's multiline mode doesn't consider an empty string after the last newline to be a line of its own. That is, it treats `A\nB` and `A\nB\n` as both being two lines, while `A\nB\nC` as being three lines. This differs from Python's multine mode, which treats [every newline as starting a new line](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.M):

> `re.M`: When specified, the pattern character `'^'` matches at the beginning of the string and at the beginning of each line (**immediately following each newline**)

You can mimic the behavior of Perl's multiline mode by adding a lookahead assertion for at least one character at the start of the line:

```
(?=.|\n)
```

Note that we need to explicitly permit `\n` with an alternative `|`'d pattern since by default [`.` does not match `\n`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.S). Without this, the pattern would fail to match starts of lines that are immediately followed by a `\n`.

Here's how this pattern behaves in your example:

```
>>> re.sub(re.compile(r"^(?=.|\n)", re.M), "[stamp]", "message\n", count=0)
'[stamp]message\n'
>>> re.sub(re.compile(r"^(?=.|\n)", re.M), "[stamp]", "message\nmessage", count=0)
'[stamp]message\n[stamp]message'
>>> re.sub(re.compile(r"^(?=.|\n)", re.M), "[stamp]", "message\nmessage\n", count=0)
'[stamp]message\n[stamp]message\n'
>>> re.sub(re.compile(r"^(?=.|\n)", re.M), "[stamp]", "message\n\n", count=0)
'message\n[stamp]\n'
```

Comment: It's not requiring POSIX lines; Perl will work on any non-empty final line, e.g. `"message\na"`, which has a character, but no trailing newline, in the final (non-POSIX) line. Seems like Perl just has a slightly different definition of line (similar to the one used by Python's `str.splitlines` method); Perl does not view a string ending in a newline as ending with a completely empty line, Python's `re` does.

Comment: @ShadowRanger so can we change the positive lookahead assertion somehow to just require there is at least 1 char there like using '.'?

Comment: @snoopyjc: That wouldn't be enough, because `.` doesn't match newlines by default, so `"message\n\n"` (where the second line is just a newline and nothing else) would only add `[stamp]` once, not twice. Adding `re.S` (aka `re.DOTALL`) to the flags works (`re.M | re.S`), but unclear if that might cause something else to behave weirdly.

Comment: Thanks - does this work in general? E.g. $STRING =~ s/$PATTERN/$REPLACEMENT/gm => re.sub(re.compile(r'PATTERN(?=.)", re.M), REPLACEMENT, STRING), whenever the use uses the M flag I can change their regex like this?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yeah adding the S flag to the user's regex is not safe.  How about if we use (?=[.\n]) for the lookahead then?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Would you be interest in posting an answer stating as much? I'm happy to interpret your feedback and update this one, but at this point it's really your answer, not mine

Comment: @snoopyjc: That seems reasonable at first glance, but [it seems to doesn't seem to work with a character class](https://tio.run/##DcpBCoAgEEDRfaeIWTkQblpHJ@gEamAxlJA6jLbo9ObmLx6fv3rnNLcWImepo9DAElJVQiw9@syRw0NKYFfrYrRNDmHqn95Ql/dQYEr1kV1HiFSKv8gmQMTWfg "Python 3 – Try It Online"). `r"^(?=.|\n)"` works though. *shrugs*

Comment: @Brian: [If you insist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75441868/364696). :-)

Comment: I just tested your solution with $message = "message\n\nmes\nmmm";
 and it now does the same in perl and python.  But my question  remains -  do you think this will work with any user-supplied regex, given they have the M flag set?

Comment: @snoopyjc: You're proposing replacing a leading `^` with `^(?=.|\n)` in any user-defined pattern? It *should* work; the `?=` is zero-width, so the remainder of their regex would match as normal, but regex is weird enough that I'd never make a 100% guarantee for completely arbitrary regex.

Comment: @snoopyjc: And yup, I came up with a way to break the simple "replace leading `^`" approach: `r"abc|^"`. The `^` is hidden by the alternation, so you won't see it at the beginning of the pattern. Like I said, regex is weird.

Comment: For /abc|^/ Do you think r"abc|^(?=.|\n)" is the right answer, in other words, change all '^' to '^(?=.|\n)', not just leading?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Perl doesn't consider the empty string after the `\n` to be a line of text, but Python does.  So the Perl's RegEx code sees `"message\n"` as one line of text, but Python's RegEx code sees it as two.

You can resolve this difference by having the Python code check for a final `\n`.  If it detects one, remove that `\n` *before* running the regular expression, and then add it back in *after*.

You will probably want to check all edge cases, too.  For example, how do the Perl and Python code behave if the entire message itself is an empty string?  (Will the Perl code do anything in that case?  How about the Python code?)

If all your messages are guaranteed to be non-zero-length text ending in a newline, then you can probably get away with just removing the final `\n`, applying the Python regex code, and then appending that `\n` back in.  But it would still be good form to consider all edge cases.

---

ADDITION:

Although it's tempting to come up with a regular expression in Python that exactly mimics the one in Perl, I wouldn't necessarily recommend it -- especially if the Python regex is so complicated that it's not easy to tell what it's doing at first or second glance.

Regular expressions don't always handle algorithmic logic very gracefully.  So if you can eliminate regexp complexity by introducing some simple algorithmic logic, I would recommend doing that instead.

In other words, you won't win any awards by using overly-complicated regular expressions, so why not use a simple regex paired with simple non-regex algorithmic logic instead?  (The future maintainers of your code will thank you!)

---

Here's a recommendation:

```
import re
message = "message\n"
message = re.sub(r"(?m:^)", "[stamp]", message)
# Remove the final "[stamp]" if it appears alone at the end:
message = message.removesuffix("[stamp]")
```

It's simple and easy to follow, and the only part of it that might be confusing is if you've never seen the `m` flag used inside of a regular expression like `(?m:...)` before.

Just be sure to test this out on edge cases (like empty messages) before you decide to use it.  You don't want to leave your program's logic to behavior you didn't realize existed.

Comment: See @Shadowranger's comment on the other answer

Comment: @snoopyjc: I don't think my comment is relevant to this answer; stripping a *single* trailing newline before replacement, and adding it back (only if there was a trailing newline to start with) should make the two languages agree, it's just a lot more verbose than slight tweaks to the regex.

Comment: I meant your other comment :-)